# Yarn Install Problems

Tags: javascript, node.js

trying to install yarn in node.js. I typed in `corepack enable` and got the following error.

> Internal Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/pnpm.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/pnpm'
> Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/pnpm.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/pnpm'

I have also read some other replies and they suggested `sudo` but it is asking me for a password and then not allowing me to type when its given. Any help will be deeply appreciated!

Comment: You have to type the root password "blind", without any feedback. That's the way it is in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run `corepack enable` as normal user without using sudo.

I had the same error message. For me it was a problem with my node installation. Instead of installing node and nvm through my packet manager (apt, dnf, brew .. depending on your system) I removed node and nvm and re-installed it following the [instructions from the nvm git repository](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md#installing-and-updating)

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.2/install.sh | bash
```

The script clones the nvm repository to ~/.nvm, and attempts to add the source lines from the snippet below to the correct profile file (~/.bash_profile, ~/.zshrc, ~/.profile, or ~/.bashrc).

```
    export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

after that either open a new terminal or source your settings file

```
bash: source ~/.bashrc

zsh: source ~/.zshrc

ksh: . ~/.profile
```

Now you should be able to verify your installation with

```
command -v nvm
```

With a working nvm I installed node like this

```
nvm install node # "node" is an alias for the latest version
```

and finally could run `codepack enable` without any trouble.